# How to make chained api calls in spring webflux/webclient

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am creating a aggregator service which needs to call an api and based on response of make second call and so on. So i am calling chain of apis each dependent on response of previous one.

```
Example Scenario:
    request 1 {"Date1" : "2019-03-03"}    
    response 1 {"price" : 10}
    request 2 {"Date1" : "2019-03-03", "price":10}
    response 2 {"recommendedPrice" : 8}
    request 2 {"Date1" : "2019-03-03", "price":10, "recommendedPrice":8}
    and so on
```

I have created this

```
public Mono<Result> getFinalRes(Request req){
    res = client.post()
    .uri(url)                                                                                                                           
    .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(request))
    .exchange()
    .flatMap(res -> res.bodyToMono(PriceTuple.class))   

    return res.subscribe(res -> getApi2(res,request ))
}
                        Or

public Mono<Result> getFinalRes(Request req){
    res = client.post()
    .uri(url)                                                                                                                           
    .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(request))
    .exchange()
    .flatMap(res -> getApi2(res,request ))   

}
```

getApi2() is again doing similar kind of thing. Am i right to do chaining in such a way or there is some better way of doing this kind of request chaining.

Comment: Could you provide the signature for the `getApi2` method?

Comment: return type of this method will vary depends on on which place i will use it. it takes two argument response from previous call and request from current call.